# Assign mltiple values to one variable in VBA for Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I am trying to write a code, where I would assign several values to be combined in one variable. The values cannot be manually entered! They are being assigned depending on the Form entry that I have!

```
value1 = 20
value2 = "Hey"
value3 = 00
```

Now I want to store all of them combines into one variable:

```
result = value1 + value2 + value3
```

This doesnt work as I wrote above.

I want this to be the result:

```
result = 20Hey00
```

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `&` instead of `+` ? and perhaps convert the numbers into strings? `value3 = 00` seems dodgy a bit cause if it was a numerical it would have been a single `0` and if it was supposed to be a String it should be wrapped up with quotes `value3 = "00"`

Comment: The & has worked. Thank you very much for the tip on other things to! New to VBA

Comment: Ok I have reposted this as an answer. Please consider accepting it to mark your question as solved. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `&` instead of `+`? AFAIK, the `+` only works if all the variables are of `String` type but in your case it seems you've got some mixed types `Long/Int`.

Additionally, `value3 = 00` seems a bit dodgy because if it was a numerical it would have been evaluated to a single `0` and if it was supposed to be a `String` it should be wrapped up with quotes `value3 = "00"`